# Get the previous day date as variable in batch file from powershell command output

Tags: powershell, batch-file, batch, batch-processing, variables

The scenario is like this. I need a previous day date (i.e. Today -1) as variable in a batch file. But if previous day is Sunday (i.e. script running on Monday) it should return the Saturday's date (i.e. Today -2). I have tried the below script but it doesnt seems to be working. Can anybody help please.

```
ECHO STARTING
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`powershell -Command "& {if ^(^([Int] ^(Get-Date^).DayOfWeek^) -eq 1^) {get-date^(^(get-date^).addDays^(-2^)^) -uformat "%%d.%%m.%%Y"} Else{get-date^(^(get-date^).addDays^(-1^)^) -uformat "%%d.%%m.%%Y"} }`) DO (SET var=%%F)

ECHO DATE CAPTURED IN VARIABLE IS %var%
```

I have tried following command directly at command promt and it is working properly.

```
powershell -Command "& {if (([Int] (Get-Date).DayOfWeek) -eq 1) {get-date((get-date).addDays(-2)) -uformat "%d.%m.%Y"} Else{get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -uformat "%d.%m.%Y"} }
```

Comment: you could save it to a file &b then import it, OR set an `$env:Var` and read that, OR switch entirely to powershell since that is so much easier to understand ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Save

```
if (((Get-Date).DayOfWeek.value__) -eq 1) {get-date((get-date).addDays(-2)) -uformat "%d.%m.%Y"} Else{get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -uformat "%d.%m.%Y"}
```

as a .ps1 file; for example C:\Batch\getvar.ps1

Then call this in your batch script with

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Batch\getvar.ps1`) DO (SET var=%%F)
```